# Query data from two tables based on unique id

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a php page where I enter a unique product ID and after hitting Search the details of that product are displayed back.

The database has two tables, Product_general wich contains ID, price, stock and another table Product_data wich contains ID, name, size. 
ID the connection between tables.

I want to display both the ID, price and name on the page.

I read about using JOIN on query but I became a little confused after reading so many tutorials.

Here is the query I have now, this displays product ID and price, I would also like to include the name of the products wich is found in the second table.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Product_general WHERE product_id = 1";
```

Then I use

```
echo $row['ID']; 
echo $row['price'];
```

Thank You !

Comment: You could try something like: select * from Product_general pg left join Product_second_table pst on pg.idSecondTable = pst.id... or something like this..

Comment: You should really read some good books or tutorials about SQL... this sort of queries are something very common and fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two tables, `product_general` and `product_data`, both of which have an `id` field.

You can join them easily:

```
select pg.id, pg.price, pd.name
from product_general as pg inner join product_data as pd on pg.id = pd.id;
```

Comment: Hi, I reached a sql query finally, it looks like this `$sql="SELECT p.product_id, p.model, p.price, pd.description FROM oc_product as p inner join oc_product_description as pd on p.product_id = pd.product_id WHERE p.product_id = '".$q."'";`  $q is a variable containing the id inserted by the user in the search box. What do you think, is it ok ?

Comment: I think it is. I would recommend you to remove the single quotes of the `where` condition if `product_id` is integer and you can ensure that `$q` is also an integer. Your query is ok, but it is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I suggest you look into prepared statements.